# How to fix MySQL error code 1064 with foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lineitem (
line_no         INT(11)                                             NOT NULL,
line_invoiceId  INT(11) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES invoice(inv_id)      NOT NULL,
line_productId  INT(11) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES products(id)         NOT NULL,
line_price      DECIMAL(10,2)                                       NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (line_no, line_invoiceId)
);
```

> ERROR CODE 1064

Comment: Hi nnnrr, welcome to SO!  Debugging sql outside the database context is difficult.  Can you provide more information about the context?

Answer (score 2):

Remove `FOREIGN KEY`. You are using the abbreviated syntax here, not the full blown SQL syntax for foreign key constraints.

For example:

```
create table invoice (inv_id int(11) primary key not null);

create table products (id int(11) primary key not null);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lineitem (
  line_no        INT(11) NOT NULL,
  line_invoiceId INT(11) NOT NULL REFERENCES invoice(inv_id),
  line_productId INT(11) NOT NULL REFERENCES products(id),
  line_price     DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (line_no, line_invoiceId)
);
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc4ddf).